# Run Same Audio at Same Time without Multiple HTTP Requests

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, audio

I want to run the audio `'/explosion.mp3'` multiple times at the same moment.

Context: The audio is an explosion and there can be multiple explosions at the same moment.

So far, my strategy is to create multiple instances of `Audio` and run them individually.

```
var audio1 = new Audio();
audio1.src = '/explosion.mp3';

var audio2 = new Audio(); 
audio2.src = '/explosion.mp3';
//var audio2 = audio1.cloneNode();  would also work

audio1.play();
audio2.play();
```

Even though it works, the client is doing 1 HTTP request for each instance created, even if it already knows the content of `'/explosion.mp3'`. Same goes for `cloneNode` method.

Is there a way to prevent making multiple HTTP request but still have multiple instance of an Audio?

Comment: You can't do what you're talking about with `new Audio()`.  Check out the web audio API.  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API.
If you're looking for an off-the-shelf solution, I wrote a library which does what you want (among other things).
https://github.com/rserota/wad

Comment: Have you set caching headers?  If the file is cached properly, you may see additional 'requests' in the network inspector, but only one will actually go over the network.

Comment: @josh3736 Using express, I put `app.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.url);
  next();
 });` and the server does log multiple times the request for the same mp3 file.

Comment: What caching headers are you sending with the file?

Comment: I am using `express.static`. How can I set caching headers on `express.static` so I don't do multiple requests?